# Have 3 threads running...only receiving info from last thread....new at threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 rfid readers where I am reading rfid tags.  I am running those but for some reason I am only receiving info from the last reader(thread) that is being processed.  What am I missing? The readers are in an array containing the ipaddress, username, port, password. Can I listen on the same service for all of them? I'm new to threads........TagInventory is the name of the class where all of this is located.

Here is the code:

```
private void Start() throws AlienReaderException, IOException{
    ThreadStop = false;

     service= new MessageListenerService(3900);
     service.setMessageListener(this);
     service.startService();
    System.out.println("length of readers: "+Reader.ipAddress.length);

      for (lastThreadId = 0; lastThreadId < Reader.ipAddress.length; lastThreadId++)
      {
          m_inventory[lastThreadId] = new AlienReader(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId]);
          log.info("taginventory reader: "+ Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId]+"Thread: "+lastThreadId);
          m_run_process[lastThreadId] = new Thread(new StartInventoryThread(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId], m_inventory[lastThreadId]));
          m_run_process[lastThreadId].start();
      }
      --lastThreadId;

      try
      {
         // Thread.sleep(1000);
          Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.getMessage();
      }


}

class StartInventoryThread implements Runnable{

    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private String user;
    private String pwd;
    private AlienReader ar;


    StartInventoryThread(String ip, int port, String user, String pwd, AlienReader ar){
        this.ip=ip;
        this.port=port;
        this.user=user;
        this.pwd=pwd;
        this.ar=ar;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!stopInventory){
                startRead(ip,port,user,pwd);

            }
        } catch (AlienReaderException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public void startRead(String ip, int port, String user, String password) throws AlienReaderException, InterruptedException, UnknownHostException{
    String myIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    //System.out.println("ip"+ ip);
    AlienReader ar= new AlienReader(ip, port, user, password);
    ar.open();
     //log.info("Reader" + ar.getIPAddress());

    ar.setNotifyAddress(myIP, 3900);
    ar.setNotifyFormat(AlienClass1Reader.TEXT_FORMAT);
    //ar.setNotifyTrigger("TrueFalse");
    ar.setNotifyTrigger("Add");
    ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);
    // log.info("MessageListenerService has started for reader: " + ip);

    //complete process in here
    ar.autoModeReset();
    ar.setAutoStopTimer(5000); // Read for 5 seconds
    ar.setAutoMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);
    tagTable.setTagTableListener(tagTableListener);
    tagTable.setPersistTime(3600);

    //tagTable.setPersistTime(1800000);
    ar.close();

    long runTime = 10000; // milliseconds
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     do {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     } while(service.isRunning()
     && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) < runTime);

     // Reconnect to the reader and turn off AutoMode and TagStreamMode.
    // log.info("\nResetting Reader");
    ar.open();
    ar.autoModeReset();
    ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.OFF);
    ar.close();

}

public static void main(String args[]){

      Thread thr=new Thread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
              try {
                new TagInventory();
            } catch (AlienReaderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
      });
  thr.start();
}
```

Comment: What is `AlienReader`? Does it perhaps have `static` fields? --- What does `startRead(...)` do?

Comment: AlienReader creates the reader that I use to read rfid tags. StartRead() method creates the alienreader object, starts the reader and receives a message with rfid tag info....adding startread code now.....@Andreas

Comment: *"`StartRead()` method creates the `AlienReader` object"*? Why?!? You already have one in the `ar` field! --- Also, your question is about why the reading from the first two isn't working, the reading being done in code not shown in the question, so how did you envision us helping you find your bug, if we can't even see the **relevant** code?

Comment: Can you listen at the same address/port. Where is your main method? You should try to reduce this down to something that other people could compile.

Comment: StartRead() creates reader object, then it opens the reader, sets the notify address, format, trigger and mode of the reader. Then it sets the reader to read for 5 seconds. It sets the tags found into a tagtable. Then it closes the reader. The thread will sleep, then reader will be opened again and turned off automode and then reader closed.  When there are tags found, a message will be sent to the notification address with the tagtable info. After that I have several methods where it takes the tags and checks various items in a database. @Andreas

Comment: That sounds like clarifying descriptions that should be mentioned in the question, don't you think?

Comment: Sure....I don't do a good job measuring how much info to give......its either too much or too little. Thanks! @Andreas

Comment: Any suggestions????

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

I see a number of issues and potential hazards in your logic throughout the code. I will step through each and guide you to the corresponding concepts that align with these issues.

**Main**

In your `main(String args[])`, add a `join()` call so that the calling thread (likely the main thread) can wait until `Thread thr` finishes before exiting.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

      Thread thr=new Thread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
              try {
                new TagInventory();
            } catch (AlienReaderException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
      });
  thr.start();
  thr.join();
}
```

**Start**

Assuming you are expecting the threads to finish by the time the `Start()` function finishes I will explain how to obtain that functionality. Do not utilize `Thread.sleep()` as it is considered poor programming. Instead utilize the `join()` function. The forces the calling thread to wait or *block* until that thread has finished. The logic added below will cycle through each of the `m_run_process` and *block* until it has finished. If you have another location where you want to ensure they all finish, you can put the `for-loop` there instead.

```
private void Start() throws AlienReaderException, IOException{
    ThreadStop = false;

    service= new MessageListenerService(3900);
    service.setMessageListener(this);
    service.startService();
    System.out.println("length of readers: "+Reader.ipAddress.length);

    for (lastThreadId = 0; lastThreadId < Reader.ipAddress.length; lastThreadId++)
    {
        m_inventory[lastThreadId] = new AlienReader(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId]);
        log.info("taginventory reader: "+ Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId]+"Thread: "+lastThreadId);
        m_run_process[lastThreadId] = new Thread(new StartInventoryThread(Reader.ipAddress[lastThreadId], Reader.port, Reader.username[lastThreadId], Reader.password[lastThreadId], m_inventory[lastThreadId]));
        m_run_process[lastThreadId].start();
    }
    --lastThreadId;

    for(Thread inventoryThread : m_run_process)
        inventoryThread.join()
}
```

**StartRead**

There seems to be a lot of problems here where you are accesses non-thread-safe objects and variables; `service`, `stopInventory`, and `tagTable` (without seeing the full file I am making assumptions and I do not see synchronization anywhere). Now, I recommend reading up on the **Java Memory Model**, **Java Memory Barrier**, **Atomic Operations**, **Synchronization**, **Thread-Safety**, and the **JVM**. In essence, your logic can cause overwriting of data and/or threads see different *caches* values. To rectify you must make shared, mutable instances thread-safe through synchronization and atomicity.

```
public void startRead(String ip, int port, String user, String password) throws AlienReaderException, InterruptedException, UnknownHostException{
    String myIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    //System.out.println("ip"+ ip);
    AlienReader ar= new AlienReader(ip, port, user, password);
    ar.open();
     //log.info("Reader" + ar.getIPAddress());

    ar.setNotifyAddress(myIP, 3900);
    ar.setNotifyFormat(AlienClass1Reader.TEXT_FORMAT);
    //ar.setNotifyTrigger("TrueFalse");
    ar.setNotifyTrigger("Add");
    ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);
    // log.info("MessageListenerService has started for reader: " + ip);

    //complete process in here
    ar.autoModeReset();
    ar.setAutoStopTimer(5000); // Read for 5 seconds
    ar.setAutoMode(AlienClass1Reader.ON);
    tagTable.setTagTableListener(tagTableListener);
    tagTable.setPersistTime(3600);

    //tagTable.setPersistTime(1800000);
    ar.close();

    long runTime = 10000; // milliseconds
     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     do {
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     } while(service.isRunning()
     && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) < runTime);

     // Reconnect to the reader and turn off AutoMode and TagStreamMode.
    // log.info("\nResetting Reader");
    ar.open();
    ar.autoModeReset();
    ar.setNotifyMode(AlienClass1Reader.OFF);
    ar.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Impurity. I plan to incorporate your suggestions tomorrow. The startRead method configures the reader settings. The reader is set to notify at a particular address when a message comes through.  The readers reads for 5 seconds then will sleep while receiving the message. The reader will send the message when a tag has been added to the tagtable. Then the reader reconnects and turns the automode off. The service is the messagelistenerservice where the messages are sent to. There are 3 readers that I want to have running now.

Comment: But the plan is to have 30 running at the same time.  Would it be easier to maintain if I have a threadpool?

Comment: Definitely! Threadpools are really useful and help with resource management and performance